# keep getting udefined variable for an array

Tags: php

I keep getting undefiendd variable for steps in `Text5.php` when accessing `Text2.php`. My question is how come I amgetting an undefined variable as I have included the variable `$steps` as an array:

Text5.php

```
    <?php

$steps = array(1 =>'Text1.php',2 => 'Text2.php',3 => 'Text3.php',4 => 'Text4.php',5 => 'Text6.php',6 => 'Text7.php');

function allowed_in($steps){
// Track $latestStep in either a session variable
// $currentStep will be dependent upon the page you're on

if(isset($_SESSION['latestStep'])){
   $latestStep = $_SESSION['latestStep'];
}
else{
   $latestStep = 0;
}
$currentStep = basename(__FILE__); 

$currentIdx = array_search($currentStep, $steps);
$latestIdx = array_search($latestStep, $steps);

if ($currentIdx - $latestIdx == 1 )
    {
       $currentIdx = $_SESSION['latestStep'];
       return 'Allowed';
    }
    return $latestIdx;
}

?>
```

Text2.php

```
            if (allowed_in()=== "Allowed")
    {
        //Text2.php code
    }
    else
        {
$page = allowed_in()+1;
?>

<div class="boxed">
<a href="<?php echo $steps[$page] ?>">Link to Another Page</a>
</div>

<?php   

}

?>
```

Comment: What do Text2.php and Text5.php have to do with each other?  How are they called? Are they in the same scope? Are they different HTTP requests?

Comment: You should also be getting another error, similar to ***Warning:** Missing argument 1 in call to allowed_in()*. What do you expect to happen when you don't pass the right parameters to functions?

Comment: The code posted isn't even syntactically valid (`echo $steps[$page[]`)

Comment: @swapnesh Tried it but still get undefined variable for $steps

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I tried to limit down the code, I will post the whole code so you can see what it looks like

Comment: @DCoder Let me post the full code, I don't get a warning like that in my full code

Comment: Code updated to full code

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable"  and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is how come I amgetting an undefined variable as I have included the variable $steps as an array

You never actually called `allowed_in` with any array.

Both `if (allowed_in()=== "Allowed")` and `$page = allowed_in()+1;` calls the `allowed_in()` function without any parameters, and in your function:

`function allowed_in($steps){` you specify that there MUST be a variable (that we create name `$steps`).

You can create default parameters by using the `=` sign:

```
function allowed_in($steps = array()){
    //Logic
}
```

Which means you can now call it with no parameters.

You might also be looking for `global` in case it's because your `$steps` variable is in the global scope:

```
function allowed_in(){
    global $steps;
    //Logic
}
```